# Feature not installing, don't know why

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a project that's built on SharePoint Smart Templates.
I don't have a web part, so I deleted the cs file.

Instead all I have is a blank feature.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
     Id="{6447a5a5-c6c7-4aee-b7c5-b7417e30c03f}"
     Title="My Content Types"
     Description="Contains the Content Types used by My Provided Applications"
     Scope="Site"
     >

    <ElementManifests>
       <ElementManifest Location="Manifest.xml"/>
   </ElementManifests>
  </Feature>
```

Any idea why this feature won't install?

**update**

I manually installed the feature using straight copy and stsadm - this worked, so its not the feature code in question, rather the project could be "whacked"

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: No error, and I checked the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES directory - the folder for the feature does not exist.... maybe I shouldn't be using smart templates?

Comment: How do you deploy your feature? What automated tools do you use?

Comment: I was using WSP Builder, the problem was the smart templates, and I've done away with them. I've reverted back to using good old WSP Builder, that is one addon you can really trust, that and SharePoint Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did away with smart templates, obviously I am not smart enough to use them, and have reverted back to normal WSP Builder, and its working great.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is scoped at site level. Try to see if you have it in Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features.

Comment: checked there doesn't exist :( - also the feature directory does not exist in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES